# Accept multiple input field in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm learning redux and can able to update single input field but when there's more than 1 input field can't able to update state of both input field!

Here's my code please check it.

My main index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import  {FormReducer}  from "./reducers/name";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

const store = createStore(FormReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,

  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

My presentational and input field component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import * as actions from "./actions";

class App extends Component {
  inputData = event => {
    this.props.actions.addToDo({ name: event.target.value });
  };
  submitData = event => {
    console.log(this.props.name);
    // console.log(this.props.mobile);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitData}>
          FirstName:
          <input
            type="text"
            name={this.props.name}
            onChange={this.inputData}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name={this.props.mobile}
            onChange={this.inputData2}
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        {this.props.name}
        {this.props.mobile}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  mobile: state.mobile,
  name: state.name
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

**In my presentational component I want to make input acceptance such like array like [event.target.name]:event.target.value or something like this.
But when I try to do this with redux it's not working properly. Please check my code and give your input!**

My reducer function:

```
let init = {
  name: ''
}

export const FormReducer = (state = init, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_NAME":
      return {...state, name:action.name, mobile:action.mobile}
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

My action function which takes action on new input:

```
let init = {
  name: ''
}

export const FormReducer = (state = init, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_NAME":
      return {...state, name:action.name, mobile:action.mobile}
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And also as you can see I want to print both name and mobile both but it's only printing on which I'm working. Please give code so that I can able to print both simultaneously.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I try to do it but then also it didn't worked so I removed it.

Comment: Actually I was thinking to add function but I have more than 12 inout fields and for every field I can't write separate functions. So I want some dynamic array like thing over here......

Comment: yes, correct ...

Comment: @Raviteja can you show it in code.... as I've shared sandbox link. Because I know how to do it without redux and store at local state, but don't know in redux. Sandbox link: codesandbox.io/s/vql3xopmpy

Comment: Ok, I will use local state here but what if I want to send that data to other component?

Comment: Can I use local state and redux in same component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this.

Use [`ecma6#computed property name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) `[event.target.name]`

```
inputData = event => {
    this.props.actions.addToDo({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };
```

EDIT :

in reducers,add this .

```
 let init = {
  name: { key : "name", value : "" },
  mobile: { key: "mobile", value: "" },
};
```

**reducer :**

```
case "ADD_NAME":
    console.log(action,state);
    return {
      ...state,
      name: {
        ...state.name, value: action.name||state.name.value
      },
      mobile: {
        ...state.mobile,
        value: action.mobile || state.mobile.value
      }
    };
```

If you checked in render,both input field need `name` attribute  which is not initialised and coming blank via `props` mapped in `mapStateToProps`.
So,you are not getting `name` attribute in event handler.

Need to initilise it.I assumed `mobile` and `name`.

Comment: @NehaDobia yes it should be work,with current approach its just repacing the `name` everytime with diff value

Comment: @NehaDobia also dont know about `addToDo`.but also check reducers action ,whether you getting the update value from dispatch action or not

Comment: If I post my code in sandbox can you verify it, because I tried and it's not working.....

Comment: sure,please share the link

Comment: it's removing first field values as I write second input tag.. please check it

Comment: It's working completely, let me get through it! Thanks.

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN I gone through your answer I have query, you wrote like:

value: action.name||state.name.value, so exactly what action.name will do? According to my thinking it will assign value, right? And you placed or operator between so if value is unassigned then it will assign and then print something like that? Please give detailed answer about this phase!

Comment: yes right,as you dispatching the vaye in single action,to avoid blank replacement,we do validity check.You can implement it as you wish

Answer (score 0):

1rst make state and save field inputs there like this.

```
state = {
    username: "",
    password: ""
  }
```

where updateValue will save values from inputs to state

```
  updateValue = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

<input type="text" name="username"  value={this.state.username} onChange={(e) => this.updateValue(e)} />
<input type="password" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={(e) => this.updateValue(e)} />
```

then you can collect data from state and pass it to your function, for example like this login form.

```
  submitData = event => {
   const user = {
     username: this.state.username,
     password: this.state.password
   }
   // now pass this `user` to your action
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```